# ActiveSupport MessageVerifier InvalidSignature error handling not working as expected

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redirect, activesupport

All,

I have a view which, onload, executes some JQuery code to populate a select_tag box:

```
var request = $.get("getLocalSuites");
```

getLocalSuites routes to the following function in the controller:

```
  def getLocal
    myPass = sessionPass
    if (myPass != nil)
      puts "4"
      result = @@p4object.getLocalSuites(sessionUser,myPass)
      render :json => result
    end
  end
```

Where sessionPass and sessionUser functions are defined:

```
  def sessionUser()
    myConnectedUser = ConnectedUser.find_by username: cookies[:username]
    return myConnectedUser[:username]
  end

  def sessionPass()
    begin
    myConnectedUser = ConnectedUser.find_by username: cookies[:username]
    puts "1"
    verifier = ActiveSupport::MessageVerifier.new(cookies[:session])
    puts "2"
    mysession = verifier.verify(myConnectedUser[:password])
    rescue ActiveSupport::MessageVerifier::InvalidSignature
      puts "3"
      redirect_to sign_in_session_expired_url
    end
    puts mysession
    return mysession
  end
```

So in other words - my jQuery calls getLocal, which finds a username and password stored in the DB. It then verifies the returned encrypted password against a session cookie. If this verification fails, it should redirect back to the sign in page, rather than try to continue to render the current page.

The server log is correctly showing `Redirected to http://localhost:3000/sign_in_session_expired` ... but rather than seeing the sign in screen, the "original" view (with select_tag etc) is rendered - with the LocalSuites select_tag populated with some sort of HTML - each character as a new row: `<!DOCTYPE html> <html   etc etc`

Can anyone explain what I am misunderstanding here - why my redirect appears to work (according to server log) - but doesn't actually happen?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The browser is not redirected automatically, since the redirect is received within an `AJAX` call, and not a regular browser `GET`, so the browser does not handle `redirects`.

See this question: [How to manage a redirect request after a jQuery Ajax call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/199099/how-to-manage-a-redirect-request-after-a-jquery-ajax-call)

> I had a similar problem to yours. I perform an ajax request that has 2
>   possible responses: one that redirects the browser to a new page and
>   one that replaces an existing HTML form on the current page with a new
>   one. The jquery code to do this looks something like:
>
> ```
> $.ajax({
>     type: "POST",
>     url: reqUrl,
>     data: reqBody,
>     dataType: "json",
>     success: function(data, textStatus) {
>         if (data.redirect) {
>             // data.redirect contains the string URL to redirect to
>             window.location.href = data.redirect;
>         }
>         else {
>             // data.form contains the HTML for the replacement form
>             $("#myform").replaceWith(data.form);
>         }
>     }
> });
> ```
>
> The JSON object "data" is constructed on the server to have 2 members:
>   data.redirect and data.form. I found this approach to be much better.

Comment: Thanks Uri - took a bit of experimenting with the server side JSON construction, and then it still didn't work. Then I realised I was editing the wrong view (another one that does something vaguely similar!)... All looks lovely now! Great stuff!